# How to include the lastrow of data if only 1 row of data exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that copy a column of data from second row to last filled row in Sheet1 and paste it in Sheet2's next empty row.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   .Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=100", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=999"
   On Error Resume Next
      Set rng1 = .Range("H2:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Resize _
          (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1). SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
      .Range(H2:I & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
      Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   End If
End With
```

This code works fine when there is more than 1 row of filtered data and it also stops copying if there is no data after filtered.

The problem now is, sometimes my filtered data only comes with 1 row of data.

```
.Range(H2:I & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

^This line of code does **not** copy 1 row of filtered data. Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: instead of including `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row` in the copy statement, store  the value of it first and test/modify based on its value before doing your copy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = .Range("H2:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Resize _
      (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
```

If there is only the header row and 1 data row this means rows `1:2` are there. This means `Range("H2:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)` will give you `H2:I2` now you resize that to `2 - 1` and `Offset` by `1` so you are at `H3:I3`.

That looks wrong to me.

Also check the value of `Debug.Print .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row` right before you copy.

Comment: Hi I tweaked the code a little bit to `rng1 = .Range("H2:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Resize _
      (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp.Row - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellType` and it works. But can I seek your help to validate this line of code should give me H2:I2?

Comment: @JeffCh I don't get what your question is.

Comment: I just wanted someone to countercheck if I removed `Offset(1, 0)` from the line of code, I should be getting H2:I2 and not H3:I3 like you mentioned above.

Comment: @JeffCh yes, that's correct.